# Changing the image source (and back again) of a group of <img> tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of image tags (around 30) that I need to change the source of depending on the value of a variable.

How can I quickly and easily do this without writing a different function for each one?

Obviously I can easily change each one with something like

```
$('#imagethatneedschanging').attr('src', 'alternateimage.png');
```

But when do that how can I then revert to the original src without writing the opposite and for each and every image tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, give them all a class so that you can reference all the images as a group, rather than individually by ID.

This function would do what you need...

```
function setImageSrc(src) {
    $("img.yourClass").attr("src", function() {
        if (src == "") {
            return $(this).data("original-src");
        }
        else {
            $(this).data("original-src", this.src);
            return src;
        }
    });
}
```

You can then call it like this to set all the images...

```
setImageSrc("alternateimage.png");
```

That would set the images to show the alternative image, and also store the original src value on each image element.  You could then revert them all back to the original by calling the same function, but like this...

```
setImageSrc("");
```

Comment: This did work thanks, but do you know why it wouldn't persist from session to session within a cordova project? Seems like I may need to commit a value to local storage?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  If you mean closing the app and then running it again then yes, definitely look at using localStorage.  It would be trivial to make that function store a value and then you'd just have to get the value when the app started and run the function with it.

Comment: I got it all squared away, didn't need local storage in the end I was just accidentally calling `setImageSrc('')` on open.

Comment: Ah okay.  Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery each to iterate through the images and use a data attribute for the original image

```
var original = false;
$( "img" ).each(function( index ) {
   if(!original){
      $(this).data('orig', $(this).data('src'));
      $(this).attr('src', 'alternateimage.png');
   }
   else{
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('orig'));
  }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/each/

http://api.jquery.com/data/